# List sorting with multiple attributes and mixed order

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have to sort a list with multiple attributes. I can do that in ascending order for ALL attributes easily with

```
L.sort(key=operator.attrgetter(attribute))....
```

but the problem is, that I have to use mixed configurations for ascending/descending... I have to "imitate" a bit the SQL `Order By` where you can do something like `name ASC, year DESC`.
Is there a way to do this easily in Python without having to implement a custom compare function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sort Python list with two keys but only one in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693373/sort-python-list-with-two-keys-but-only-one-in-reverse-order)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If your attributes are numeric, you have this.

```
def mixed_order( a ):
    return ( a.attribute1, -a.attribute2 )

someList.sort( key=mixed_order )
```

If your attributes includes strings or other more complex objects, you have some choices.

The `.sort()` method is stable: you can do multiple passes.  This is perhaps the simplest.  It's also remarkably fast.

```
def key1( a ): return a.attribute1
def key2( a ): return a.attribute2

someList.sort( key=key2, reverse=True )
someList.sort( key=key1 )
```

If this is the only sort, you can define your own special-purpose comparison operators.  Minimally, you need `__eq__` and `__lt__`.  The other four can be derived from these two by simple logic.

Comment: thanks! callint sort() multiple times turned out to be the perfect solution for me!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just a bit of confusion regarding the first part; does returning a tuple perform a complex sort with higher index values taking lower precedence? I guess my question is more generally, how does `cmp` behave when handed two tuples? I looked around and can't find this documented.

Comment: __eq__ can be derived from __lt__ using simple logic. :)

Comment: it might be helpful to point out that using this approach you have to reverse your sorting order (as you have done).

Answer (score 8):

A custom function will render your code more readable. If you have many sorting operations and you don't want to create those functions though, you can use lambda's:

```
L.sort(lambda x, y: cmp(x.name, y.name) or -cmp(x.year, y.year))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't, but writing the compare function is easy:

```
def my_cmp(a, b):
    return cmp(a.foo, b.foo) or cmp(b.bar, a.bar)
L.sort(my_cmp)
```