# How to write sort key functions for descending values?

Tags: python, sorting

The move in recent versions of Python to passing a *key* function to `sort()` from the previous *cmp* function is making it trickier for me to perform complex sorts on certain objects.

For example, I want to sort a set of objects from newest to oldest, with a set of string tie-breaker fields. So I want the dates in reverse order but the strings in their natural order. With a comparison function I can just reverse the comparison for the date field compared to the string fields. But with a key function I need to find some way to invert/reverse either the dates or the strings.

It's easy (although ugly) to do with numbers - just subtract them from something - but do I have to find a similar hack for dates (subtract them from another date and compare the timedeltas?) and strings (...I have no idea how I'd reverse their order in a locale-independent way).

I know of the existence of `functools.cmp_to_key()` but it is described as being *"primarily used as a transition tool for programs being converted to Python 3 where comparison functions are no longer supported"*. This implies that I should be able to do what I want with the key method - but how?

Comment: Passing reverse=True just changes which of the sub-keys I need to find a way to invert. Imagine (for some strange reason) I wanted to sort by first name ascending and last name descending, for example. Passing reverse=True just means I have to find a way to invert the first name now, instead of the last name.

Comment: http://python3porting.com/preparing.html#keycmp-section

Comment: It's not clear how that link helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: List Sorting with Multiple Attributes and Mixed Order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516249/python-list-sorting-with-multiple-attributes-and-mixed-order)

Comment: A better title would be **How to sort non-numeric tuples with different orders?**

Comment: May I add an example? I've just prepared a question when I found yours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sort Python list with two keys but only one in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693373/sort-python-list-with-two-keys-but-only-one-in-reverse-order)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The slow-but-elegant way to do this is to create a value wrapper that has reversed ordering:

```
from functools import total_ordering
@total_ordering
class ReversedOrder:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other.value == self.value
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return other.value < self.value
```

If you don't have `functools.total_ordering`, you'd have to implement all 6 comparisons, e.g.:

```
import operator
class ReversedOrder:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
for x in ['__lt__', '__le__', '__eq__', '__ne__', '__ge__', '__gt__']:
    op = getattr(operator, x)
    setattr(ReversedOrder, x, lambda self, other, op=op: op(other.value, self.value))
```

Comment: If the only use for `ReversedOrder` is for use in a sort key then you only need to implement `__lt__` and can safely ignore all of the others.

Comment: @Duncan where is that documented?  I can't find it in the reference.

Comment: See the Python 3 release notes http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons . I don't know where if anywhere it is in the main docs though.

Comment: Going to accept this answer, because the other posts certainly solve the problem, but this one most closely answers the question.

Comment: @Duncan: There is an explicit guarantee in [`list.sort`'s docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort): "This method sorts the list in place, using only `<` comparisons between items." [The Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#odd-and-ends) explicitly adds that "The sort routines are guaranteed to use `__lt__()` when making comparisons between two objects. So, it is easy to add a standard sort order to a class by defining an `__lt__()` method:" ("sort routines" referring to both `list.sort` and `sorted` in this context).

Answer (score 26):

The most generic way to do this is simply to sort separately by each key in turn. Python's sorting is always stable so it is safe to do this:

```
sort(data, key=tiebreakerkey)
sort(data, key=datekey, reverse=True)
```

will (assuming the relevant definitions for the key functions) give you the data sorted by descending date and ascending tiebreakers.

Note that doing it this way is slower than producing a single composite key function because you will end up doing two complete sorts, so if you can produce a composite key that will be better, but splitting it out into separate sorts gives a lot of flexibility: given a key function for each column you can make any combination of them and specify reverse for any individual column.

For a completely generic option:

```
keys = [ (datekey, True), (tiebreakerkey, False) ]
for key, rev in reversed(keys):
    sort(data, key=key, reverse=rev)
```

and for completeness, though I really think it should be avoided where possible:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key
sort(data, key=cmp_to_key(your_old_comparison_function))
```

The reason I think you should avoid this you go back to having `n log n` calls to the comparison function compared with `n` calls to the key function (or `2n` calls when you do the sorts twice).

Comment: +1 for the same reason as katrielalex: it does address the problem, although I don't think it counts as 'a' key function, and I think it is less elegant than a comparison function.

Comment: Even though it is slower than a composite key function it will probably still be a lot faster than a comparison function. It is also possible to write a cmp_to_key wrapper that will wrap any comparison function up to be used as a key function instead, but that's really messy

Comment: There's a cmp_to_key in the functools module so you could argue that's cleaner than having to generalise to multiple sorting passes. But mostly I'm just surprised that the `cmp` option has been removed when it's clearly the cleaner way to perform some sorts.

Comment: `cmp` is much slower than using `key` especially when you have custom comparison. With a `key` function the custom Python code is called `n` times and then (usually) much faster builtin code used to compare a simple object or tuple of objects for `n log n` comparisons. With `cmp` you get the full `n log n` calls to the Python code.

Comment: I appreciate the speed differences, but it's rare for Python to implement optimisations that make the code significantly uglier. Why not just leave in the 2 code paths and document that `key` is faster?

Comment: Python 3 dropped `cmp` and `__cmp__` altogether, in particular `sort` now only requires `__lt__` to be defined for the keys. This has advantages if you want to sort objects which cannot implement a full comparison as well as reducing the scope for errors when `__lt__` and `__cmp__` produce inconsistent results. There's an explanation here: http://python3porting.com/problems.html#comparisons

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Sort_Stability_and_Complex_Sorts specifically recommends this method for complex sorting, and notes that *the Timsort algorithm used in Python does multiple sorts efficiently because it can take advantage of any ordering already present in a dataset*.

Answer (score 12):

I think the docs are incomplete.  I interpret the word "primarily" to mean that there are still reasons to use cmp_to_key, and this is one of them.  `cmp` was removed because it was an "attractive nuisance:" people would gravitate to it, even though `key` was a better choice.

But your case is clearly better as a `cmp` function, so use `cmp_to_key` to implement it.

Comment: +1 I agree with this answer, nothing wrong with using the solution already provided by functools in those (rarer) cases where using a cmp function is the more elegant way.

Comment: I wonder why this function wasn't just overloaded for the two use cases, even with the equivalent mapping structure being possible.

Answer (score 6):

Sort twice, once on each key and once reversed.

(Python `sort` is [*stable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability); that is, it doesn't change the order of the original list unless it has to.)

<sub>It *does* matter which order you do the sorts in, if you care about how equal elements get sorted.</sub>

Comment: Nice idea. Still, I'd consider that a bit hacky compared to a custom comparison function, and it doesn't work well in my code base (where I pick a sort key based on input and then call `sort()` once with it), but it is certainly a way around the problem.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `pandas` library and args `ascending`, setting the columns you want to sort ascending and the columns you want descending by doing e.g. `ascending=[True,False,False]`

You can do that not only for ***two*** levels (e.g. `datetime` and `str`) but to ***any*** number of levels needed.

For example, if you have

```
d = [[1, 2, datetime(2017,1,2)], 
     [2, 2, datetime(2017,1,4)],
     [2, 3, datetime(2017,1,3)],
     [2, 3, datetime(2017,1,4)], 
     [2, 3, datetime(2017,1,5)], 
     [2, 4, datetime(2017,1,1)], 
     [3, 1, datetime(2017,1,2)]]
```

You can setup your `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

and use `sort_values`

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=[0,1,2], ascending=[True,False,False])
sorted_list = sorted_df.agg(list, 1).tolist()


[[1, 2, Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00')],
 [2, 4, Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')],
 [2, 3, Timestamp('2017-01-05 00:00:00')],
 [2, 3, Timestamp('2017-01-04 00:00:00')],
 [2, 3, Timestamp('2017-01-03 00:00:00')],
 [2, 2, Timestamp('2017-01-04 00:00:00')],
 [3, 1, Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00')]]
```

Notice that the first column is sorted ascending, and the second and third are descending, which is of course due to setting `ascending=[True,False,False]`.

Answer (score 0):

For String, you can use some commonly acknowledged maximum value (such as 2^16 or 2^32) and use chr(), unicode(), ord() to do the math, just like for integers.

In one of my work, I know I deal with strings in utf8 and their ordinals are below 0xffff, so I wrote:

```
def string_inverse(s):
    inversed_string = ''
    max_char_val = 0xffff
    for c in s:
        inversed_string += unicode(max_char_val-ord(c))
    return inversed_string        

result.sort(key=lambda x:(x[1], string_inverse(x[0])), reverse=True)
```

x is of type: (string, int), so what I get is, to abuse the SQL:

```
select * from result order by x[1] desc, x[0] asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
>>> import functools
>>> reverse_key = functools.cmp_to_key(lambda a, b: (a < b) - (a > b))
>>> reverse_key(3) < reverse_key(4)
False
>>> reverse_key(3) > reverse_key(4)
True
>>> reverse_key('a') < reverse_key('b')
False
```