# Set Ascending Descending for each column when sorting by multiple columns

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list `d` that I wish to sort. I sort by the first column first. If its a tie there I then go on to use the second column to sort. Say I want to sort by the first column in ascending order but sort by the second column in descending order. Ascending being the default, using the `reverse` key I thought the below should work.

```
sorted(d,key=lambda x: (x[0],x[1]),reverse=(False,True))
```

But it does not. It give the following error.

```
    reverse=(False,True))

TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

So if I'm not doing it right how to fix it? Or the way to do this is completely different? Advice on that would be helpful.

My question indeed has some duplication but there are already interesting responses, so I would like to keep it.

Comment: Are the values numeric? If so, you can use negation to reverse the sort order for the second element: `sorted(d,key=lambda x: (x[0],-x[1]))`. It would be helpful if you shared a sample of your list `d`.

Comment: @pault good point. Some coloumns can indeed be strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

> *reverse* is a boolean value. If set to `True`, then the list elements are sorted as if each comparison were reversed.

So what you want instead is something like:

```
d.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))
```

If `x[1]` is not a number, try:

```
d.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
d.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: And what if `x[1]` is a string?

Comment: @pault should work now...

Answer (score 8):

(*Might be overkill, but..*) Using `pandas` and args `ascending=[True, False]`:

```
d = [[1,2], [2,2], [2,3], [2,4], [3,1]]
df=  pd.DataFrame(d)

sorted_values = df.sort_values(by=[0,1], ascending=[True,False])
sorted_list = sorted_values.agg(list,1).tolist()

[[1, 2], [2, 4], [2, 3], [2, 2], [3, 1]]
```

Comment: This is worth adding to the canonical question, which I believe is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206884/how-to-write-python-sort-key-functions-for-descending-values).

Comment: I have followed your suggestion @pault thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

My take on solution:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

l = ((1, 'b'),
     (1, 'd'),
     (2, 'a'),
     (1, 'a'))

def sort_multi(lst, index_normal, index_reversed):
    return list(chain.from_iterable([sorted(list(j), key=lambda v:v[index_reversed], reverse=True) for i, j in groupby(sorted(lst), key=lambda v:v[index_normal])]))


print(sort_multi(l, 0, 1))
```

Outputs:

```
[(1, 'd'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'a')]
```

Comment: @pault Corrected

Comment: Looks like this will work for 2 indexes- it would be really useful if you could extend it to work for any number of indices.