# Python: How to sort a list of custom objects by multiple attributes by different order?

Tags: python, sorting, comparator, string-comparison

For example, if I have a `Person` class

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"({self.name}, {self.age})"
```

and a List of `Person`

```py
persons = [
    Person("Bob", 25),
    Person("Alice", 25),
    Person("Charlie", 23),
    Person("Dave", 25),
]
```

I can sort the list by `age` in ascending order, and in case of a tie, sort by `name` in ascending order using the following method:

```
sorted_persons = sorted(persons, key=lambda p: (p.age, p.name))
```

Question:

However, I'm looking for a way to sort the list by `age` in ascending order and, in the event of a tie in age, sort by `name` in descending order. How could I achieve this in Python?

I've come up with one solution, as shown below, but it seems a bit inelegant. Is there a more succinct way to write a string comparison method that can handle all three cases (i.e., less than, equal to, and greater than)? For instance, Java has a `s1.compareTo(s2)` method that makes such comparisons straightforward.

Here's the solution I'm currently working with:

```py
from functools import cmp_to_key


def compare(p1, p2):
    cmp = p1.age - p2.age
    if cmp != 0:
        return cmp
    if p1.name < p2.name:
        return 1
    elif p1.name > p2.name:
        return -1
    return 0


sorted_persons = sorted(persons, key=cmp_to_key(compare))
```

This code correctly sorts the `persons` list first by `age` in ascending order, and then by `name` in descending order when the ages are equal. However, I feel there should be a cleaner, more Pythonic way to handle this. Any suggestions?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206884/how-to-write-sort-key-functions-for-descending-values

Answer (score 4):

Another solution:

For the purpose of sorting you can define custom `str` class where you override the `__lt__` magic method (*less than*):

```py
class reverse_cmp_string(str):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return not str.__lt__(self, other)

sorted_persons = sorted(persons, key=lambda p: (p.age, reverse_cmp_string(p.name)))
print(sorted_persons)
```

Prints:

```
[(Charlie, 23), (Dave, 25), (Bob, 25), (Alice, 25)]
```

Comment: That is a cool approach.

Answer (score 2):

This snippet of code should do it. I ran it and the output looks right

```
sorted_persons = sorted(persons, key=lambda p: (-p.age, p.name), reverse=True)
```

Comment: It works for numbers yes, but not if say strings ascending and descending though, or dates

Answer (score 2):

Python *used* to have the `cmp` built-in function which did what you want.

There was also a keyword argument callled `cmp` for `sort` and `sorted`, which is what you could have used here, but it was removed in Python 3.0+ because the `key` was often more performant than `cmp`. Unfortunately you found the one where it quite isn't.

However there is a trick you could do here: you can use tuple comparison and you can *swap* the names, therefore:

```
def compare(p1, p2):
    a = p1.age, p2.name
    b = p2.age, p1.name
```

then you can just compare these two. There is also a trick to nicely produce -1, 0, 1 by using the fact that True and False are integers with values of 1 and 0 respectively:

```
    return (a > b) - (a < b)
```

if `>` and `<` are normally defined then maximum one side will result in True, with the other being False; `True - False == 1` and `False - True == -1`, and `False - False == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Python's sort is stable.  This means that the order of items that have the same sort key is preserved in the resulting list.

You can leverage this by sorting in steps, starting with the least significant order:

```
sorted_persons = sorted(persons, key=lambda p: p.name, reverse=True)
sorted_persons.sort(key=lambda p: p.age)
```

You could also streamline the cmp_to_key to a lambda (but that's not a different solution):

```
sorted_persons = sorted(persons,key=cmp_to_key(
                 lambda a,b: a.age-b.age or (a.name<b.name)-(b.name<a.name)))
```

For a more general solution, you could create a class that will handle all descending key ordering expressed directly in the key=lambda's return tuples:

```
class descending():
    def __init__(self,value):  self.value = value
    def __lt__(self,other):    return self.value > other.value
```

usage:

```
sorted_persons = sorted( persons, key=lambda p:(p.age,descending(p.name)) )
```