# How to sort in decreasing value first then increasing in second value

Tags: python, sorting

Let say I have :

```
student_tuples = [ ('john', 'A', 15),
                   ('peter', 'B', 12),
                   ('dave', 'C', 12)]
```

How do I sort it to be like this:

```
student_tuples = [('john', 'A', 15), ('dave', 'C', 12), ('peter', 'B', 12)]
```

What I can think is:

```
from operator import itemgetter

sorted(student_tuples, key=itemgetter(2,0), reverse=True)
```

but then the output will be:

```
student_tuples = [('john', 'A', 15), ('peter', 'B', 12), ('dave', 'C', 12)]
```

and that is not what I want. How can I do  it using itemgetter or any other easier way?

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples). I think there is everything you need.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't believe this is a duplicate.  This question is specifically asking how to sort by one descending key and one ascending key, whereas the "duplicate" is only asking about multiple keys.

Comment: No, it is instead a duplicate of [Python: List Sorting with Multiple Attributes and Mixed Order](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1516249)

Comment: @RichieHindle "One [...] and one [...]" is grammatically equivalent to *multiple*; therefore, "Sort by one desc[...] and asc[...]" is the exact same as "[sorting by] multiple keys".

Comment: Not sure if it is worth re-opening then closing again though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This does it:

```
print sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda t: (-t[2], t[0]))
# [('john', 'A', 15), ('dave', 'C', 12), ('peter', 'B', 12)]
```

Comment: Sorting in two passes is a better way to go.  The negated key approach only works with numeric keys.

Answer (score 5):

Write your own key-getting function.

```
student_tuples = [ ('john', 'A', 15), ('peter', 'B', 12), ('dave', 'C', 12)]

def student_key(args):
    name, letter, number = args
    return (-number, name)

>>> sorted(student_tuples, key=student_key)
[('john', 'A', 15), ('dave', 'C', 12), ('peter', 'B', 12)]
```

Comment: definitely the most readable way

Comment: @Schoolboy Yes they are the same, saw his only when I posted my own.  I wouldn't have posted it if I had seen his.  Does SO have a policy about these situations?

Comment: @Schoolboy No, it isn't exactly the same: in Adrian's solution, there's an unpacking, that means three assignements of objects to identifiers ``name,letter,number`` that aren't necessary, as the RichieHindle's solution shows.

Comment: @eyquem That's what I said!! Let me rephrase my other comment...

Comment: No, there's nothing like a "policy" that I know of.. But sometimes, (not here i guess) people just type the same thing as someone else, just for rep.. But here in your case, the difference is too little to say that you did so, and I don't think you did it either (copied the other answer) and that it is just a co-incidence.... :)

Comment: @Schoolboy You wrote to me: "That's what I said!! Let me rephrase my other comment". No, you didn't said what I underlined. If you had said it, I wouldn't have written my comment.  And if you had said it, why would Adrian have writen "Yes they are the same" ?

Comment: What you said in your deleted comment was just that Adrian's and RichieHindle's answers were basically the same. Which is right in the principle, but not in the details. If you test the execution's times of these two solutions, you'll note that using ``(-t[2], t[0])`` instead of ``name, letter, number = args ; return (-number, name)`` is a little faster (comparison of times must be done correctly to see this). No one can verify things anymore since you deleted your comment. That's peculiar behavior. And I don't see the announced rephrasing of your deleted comment.

Answer (score 4):

Where you don't have a numeric field that can be easily negated, then you can always do a two-phase sort, relying on the fact that Python's `.sort` is stable:

```
student_tuples.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
student_tuples.sort(key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
```

Comment: +1 This is the intended way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Nest the sorts. Most important/first priority sort in the outmost sort.

```
student_tuples = [ ('john', 'A', 15),
                   ('peter', 'B', 12),
                   ('dave', 'C', 12)]

from operator import itemgetter

sorted_ = sorted(sorted(student_tuples,key = itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
```

gives

```
>>> sorted_
[('john', 'A', 15), ('dave', 'C', 12), ('peter', 'B', 12)]
```