# how to do hierarchical sorting in python?

Tags: python, sorting

So I have a 2D array of data taken from an excel spreadsheet which I'm currently sorting based on a column with data on criticality.

```
#rows contains my data that I'm sorting, it's a 2D array
searchdict = dict(Critical=1, High=2, Medium=3, Low=4)
rows.sort(key=lambda row: searchdict.get(row[11], 5))
```

I'd like to sort based on another column if it's a tie for that column, anyone know how to approach this?  Thanks in advance for any help.

FYI: the other column contains numerical data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516249/python-list-sorting-with-multiple-attributes-and-mixed-order

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a tuple in your key. This is method is generally considered more "pythonic" than doing two sorts in a row.

```
key=lambda row: (searchdict.get(row[11], 5), row[other_column]))
```

Comment: The OP said that the other column is numerical so there is no need for an other call to `searchdict.get`. (BTW: thg's answer was incorrect also because if you want to do 2 sorts you must first sort by the *secondary key*, and the by the primary key.)

Comment: Oops, you're right. And thg's answer was also incorrect because `sort()` normally returns `None` instead of the sorted list (`sorted()` is normally used for that).

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to use key with python's tuple ordering.

```
#rows contains my data that I'm sorting, it's a 2D array
searchdict = dict(Critical=1, High=2, Medium=3, Low=4)
rows.sort(key=lambda row: (searchdict.get(row[11], 5), searchdict.get(row[<secondary column index here>], 5)))
```

This plays off of the fact that the leftmost element in a tuple is considered to be more significant during comparisons, demonstrated here:

```
>>> (6, 5) > (5, 6)
True
>>> (6, 5) > (6, 4)
True
>>> (6, 5) > (6, 6)
False
>>> (2, 1, 1) > (1, 1000, 1000)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a tuple as return from your sort key function:

```
rows.sort(key=lambda row: (searchdict.get(row[11], 5), row[17]))
```

Python sorts for item with index 0 first than for item with index 1.